# My numpy array always ends in zero?

Tags: python, math, numpy

I think I missed something somewhere. I filled  a numpy array using two for loops (x and y) and a function based on the x,y position. The only problem is that the value of the array always ends in zero irregardless of the size of the array.

```
thetamap = numpy.zeros(36, dtype=float)
thetamap.shape = (6, 6)
for y in range(0,5):
    for x in range(0,5):
        thetamap[x][y] =  x+y
print thetamap
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`range(0, 5)` produces `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. The endpoint is always omitted. You want simply `range(6)`.

Better yet, use the *awesome power of NumPy* to make the array in one line:

```
thetamap = np.arange(6) + np.arange(6)[:,None]
```

This makes a row vector and a column vector, then adds them together using NumPy broadcasting to make a matrix.

Comment: Or, if you really want to go crazy with numpy methods, it's also equivalent to `np.add.outer(range(6), range(6))`.  Broadcasting is much more generally applicable, though.